# a Question About the Proof that Continuous Injection of Interval is Strictly Monotone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is taken from here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Injection_of_Interval_is_Strictly_Monotone :

Let $I$ be a real interval.
Let $f:I\to R$ be an injective continuous real function.
Then f is strictly monotone.

Proof:
Aiming for a contradiction, suppose f is not strictly monotone.
That is, there exist $x,y,z\in I$ with $x<y<z$ such that either:

$\space\space\space f(x) \le f(y)$ and $f(y) \ge f(z)$

or:

$\space\space\space f(x) \ge f(y)$ and $f(y) \le f(z)$

How can the existence of such $x,y,z$ be proven?

Comment: Try writing the definition of strictly monotone in firt order logic (with the upside down A's and backward E's), then use quantifier negation. This is a useful technique in general, especially for proofs by contrapositive or contradiction, to figure out what it means for some statement/definition/assumption to be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the definition of "not strictly monotone."

The function $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$ if for all $a,b\in I$ with $a\lt b$, we have $f(a)\lt f(b)$; it is strictly decreasing on $I$ if for all $r,s\in I$ with $r\lt s$, we have $f(r)\gt f(s)$.

So suppose $f$ is *not* strictly monotone. That means that it is not strictly increasing, so there exist $r,s\in I$ such that $r\lt s$ but $f(r)\geq f(s)$; since we are assuming $f$ is injective, in fact we can say $f(r)\gt f(s)$.

We also now that $f$ is not strictly decreasing, so there exist $a,b\in I$ such that $a\lt b$ but $f(a)\lt f(b)$.

The points $x,y,z$ that we want can now be found among $a,b,r,s$:

1. If $a\lt b\leq r \lt s$, then: if $f(r)\lt f(b)$, take $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=r$. If $f(r)\geq f(b)$, then take $x=a$, $y=r$, $z=s$.
2. If $a\leq r\leq b\leq s$, then: if $f(s)\lt f(b)$, take $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=s$. If $f(s)\gt f(b)$, take $x=r$, $y=b$, $z=s$. If $f(s)=f(b)$, then $s=b$, so we must have $r\neq a$, and then $x=a$, $y=r$, $z=b=s$ yield an example.

Similar considerations hold if $a\leq r\lt s\lt b$; the remaining cases follow symmetrically.